# jQuery, wait for a method to finish then trigger an action

Tags: jquery, promise

This is my situation. I need to run this method first

```
$(editor.image.toggleCaption);
```

and then:

```
alert('hello world');
```

If I do this:

```
$(editor.image.toggleCaption);
alert('hello world');
```

it doesn't work because the `alert` is triggered before the method is done.

The only way I could get this to work is with using setTimeout. But it's a static solution, so I'd like to avoid it. 
I tried `$.Deferred` but I don't know how to set it up, and all the combination that I tried didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this `$(editor.image.toggleCaption)` returns a promise, then you can simply do: `$(editor.image.toggleCaption).then(x => alert('hello world'));`

Comment: I can try, but what is that "x"?

Comment: See [Arrow Function MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @rolfo85 its the arrow function variable, in case your promise returns anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `when`,this seems to work.ref https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ .Replace `$('.test').hide('slow')` with your function.hope this helps

```js
$.when($('.test').hide('slow')).then(function(){
    alert(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Some Contents</div>
```